# React function updates state on second onClick?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm working on a hotel feature where the user can filter through and display the corresponding rooms available, however when I set the onClick to update the filters and display the filtered rooms, the rooms display correctly after the second click and there after.

```
const toggleSelection = (e) => {
    setFilters((prevFilters) => ({
      ...prevFilters,
      [e.name]: e.id,
    }));
    filterRooms();
  };

const filterRooms = () => {
   ....
   ....
    setRooms((prevRooms) => ({
      ...prevRooms,
      filtered: filtered_rooms,
    }));
  };
```

Comment: Can you please put more detailed code with JSX

Answer (score 1):

`useState()` (and class component's `this.setState()`) [are asynchronous](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately), so your second state updater won't have an up to date value for `filtered_rooms` when it runs.

Rather than:

```js
const [some_state, setSomeState] = useState(...);
const [some_other_state, setSomeOtherState] = useState(...);

const someHandler = e => {
  setSomeState(...);
  setSomeOtherState(() => {
    // Uses `some_state` to calculate `some_other_state`'s value
  });
};
```

You need to `setSomeOtherState` within a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook, and ensure to mark `some_state` as a dependency.

```js
const [some_state, setSomeState] = useState(...);
const [some_other_state, setSomeOtherState] = useState(...);

useEffect(() => {
  setSomeOtherState(() => {
    // Uses `some_state` to calculate `some_other_state`'s value
  });
}, [some_state]);

const someHandler = e => {
  setSomeState(...);
};
```

It is hard to give an suggestion for your code since it is fairly edited, but it'd probably look like this:

```js
const filterRooms = () => {
  // ...
  setRooms((prevRooms) => ({
    ...prevRooms,
    filtered: filtered_rooms,
  }));
};

useEffect(() => {
  filterRooms();
}, [filtered_rooms]);

const toggleSelection = (e) => {
  setFilters((prevFilters) => ({
    ...prevFilters,
    [e.name]: e.id,
  }));
};
```

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/romellem/pen/xxRWJPG?editors=1010) for a simple (albeit a bit contrived) example.